# separar el password de la tabla usuarios

Tags: mysql

hago esta pregunta mas que todo por experiencia de algunos de ustedes, quiero pedirles sus opiniones, estaría correcto separar el password de la tabla usuario teniendo en cuenta que la tabla de usuario tiene los datos personales de cada usuario, ejemplo

- **USUARIOS**
- id_usuario :autoincrement
- nombres
- apellidos
- numero_identificación

en esta tabla no guardo la contraseña. la guardo en otra tabla con referencia al id_usuario de la siguiente forma

- **LOGIN_USUARIOS**
- id_usuario_login (hace referencia al id de la tabla usuarios)
- pass_usuario

Espero que me entiendan. no quiero que la tabla usuario tenga muchos campos, por eso se me ocurrió esto, pero ustedes me pueden orientar en este caso, saludos y feliz día

Comment: El agregar el `password` no te va a generar una diferencia en cuestión de cantidad de campos en la tabla `usuarios`, pero por cuestion de seguridad si es viable separarlo en otra tabla, tal cual lo propones; ya que si te comprometen la tabla `usuarios`, no te comprometan las passwords.

Comment: @SergioKaznowiecki tu aspecto sobre la seguridad es importante y no había pensando en él. Aunque realmente es difícil que una tabla quede comprometida y otra no en un hipotético caso de ataque. No obstante, no es mala idea, si se piensa en la seguridad, separar la tabla que guarda las claves. Diría que habría que separarlas por ejemplo si se quieren aplicar políticas como tiempo de expiración de password u otras. Aunque también habría que encriptar y cosas así. O sea, la seguridad no queda del todo cubierta con sólo separar las tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando la tabla vaya por cerca de 4,000 campos, entonces el criterio que expones:

> ... no quiero que la tabla usuario tenga muchos campos

podría ser decisivo para pensar en separar los datos en una o más tablas.

Lo que quiero decir es que una tabla con 6 campos no es nada, cuando MySQL tiene un límite de **¡4096 columnas por tabla!**, aunque ese límite puede variar ligeramente:

> MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective
>   maximum may be less for a given table. The exact column limit depends
>   on several factors...
>
> ---
>
> MySQL tiene un límite fijo de 4096 columnas por tabla, pero el máximo
>   efectivo puede ser menor para una tabla determinada. El límite de
>   columna exacto depende de varios factores...
>
> <sub>- [Manual de Referencia (versión 8)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html)</sub>

Lo que sería decisivo para determinar su debe haber una tabla o más, es el contexto mismo de tu aplicación. Si un `Usuario` es una entidad única, no tiene sentido dividir las tablas por creer que 6 columnas es demasiado para el manejador... No sub-estimes a los manejadores de bases de datos.

Y... si esa tabla es lenta cuando tenga 1,000 o 200 millones de registros, no me echas la culpa a mi ni pienses que lo es porque tiene 6 columnas. Aparte de tener bien estructurado el modelo de datos tienes que tener clara la política de índices y claves primarias que vas a poner y cómo vas a inter relacionar tus tablas.

Comment: @a-cedano , gracias por aclararme la pregunta, de modo que no es necesario hacer lo que tenia pensado, de todos modos gracias por tu opinión.